# Creating LoginButton and setting View attributes programatically

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, facebook-android-sdk

I want to create the LoginButton programatically since I'm putting it in an ActionBarSherlock ActionBar.

I am able to put the `<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton>` definition in a layout file, and inflate manually.

However, when I just use: `new LoginButton(this)`, it comes out as "Log In" text, like this:

[image: Facebook Login button on ActionBarSherlock]

Is it because it's missing the `facebook:confirm_logout` and `facebook:fetch_user_info` attributes? Or other attributes?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom button and add a click listener event to that button, on click listener check for your facebook session

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}

private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry if I was not clear. I don't need a custom button. I need the SDK LoginButton to appear with the Facebook logo, as it does when placed directly in a layout.

Comment: @mparaz I think you will need a custom button. Otherwise you're trying to fit the default button into the action bar - which is something like 300dip wide and 50dip tall.

Comment: @Kyle - I guess that's it. In any case, it's not that important - it's OK to inflate the layout and use that as the custom view for the ActionBar.